# Errors when deploy a Symfony2 project

Tags: symfony, web-deployment

I'm trying to deploy my Symfony2 project into web server, but when I visited this link, `whatever.com/app.php/`appears this error:

```
Warning: require_once(/home/u627182119/public_html/../app/bootstrap.php.cache): failed to open stream:
No such file or directory in /home/u627182119/public_html/app.php on line 6 Fatal error: require_once():
Failed opening required '/home/u627182119/public_html/../app/bootstrap.php.cache' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php') in /home/u627182119/public_html/app.php on line 6
```

It's something with routes but I don't know what.

## EDIT

In "u627182119" directory have two folders:

1. `public_html` which contains all of files of `/web` directory.
2. `personal` which contains the rest of files of project.

Comment: Could you show the directory hierarchy of your "u627182119" folder please ?

Comment: I've just edited the question

Comment: unless you have some special config going on in your project you typically include the app directory on the server — notice that the path `/home/u627182119/public_html/../app/bootstrap.php.cache` is equivalent to `/home/u627182119/app/bootstrap.php.cache`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, check your hosting supports PHP 5.3 and that it fits all the requirements running config.php

Regarding your question, your hierarchy seems to be wrong. When deploying Symfony2 apps I move all the content of the web folder to the root of the server where the other main folders (app, src, vendor...) are located and I do the following changes in the app.php

```
$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/app/bootstrap.php.cache'; //Note the removed "../"
```

And some lines bellow also in app.php

```
require_once __DIR__.'/app/AppKernel.php'; // Also note the removed "../"
```